# How to find the first nearest value up and down in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like this:

[image]

When I set id =4 , the results I need are:

[image]

Note that I selected the `ID=4` and the two nearest values from both sides .

How can write sql code for do it?

Comment: Are your IDs ALWAYS running numbers, no gaps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`LEAD()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) function , that selects the next value by a specific order , like this:

**Note** that `LEAD` was only introduced to SQL-Server 2012+.

```
SELECT s.id,s.name,s.number
FROM (
    SELECT t.*
           LEAD(t.id,1) OVER(ORDER BY t.Number DESC) as Next_val,
           LEAD(t.id,1) OVER(ORDER BY t.Number) as Last_val
    FROM YourTable t) s
WHERE 4 IN(s.id,next_Val,s.last_val)
```

You can replace `4` with your desired `ID` or with a parameter .

**EDIT:** A little explanation - `LEAD` function provides a way to access the next row, without the use of a `SELF JOIN` or a `sub query` , it orders the results by the order you provided inside the `OVER()` clause, and select the value inside the parentheses - `LEAD(value)` that belong to the record above the current record that is being processed. So, this query selects each `ID` , and the `ID` that belongs to the nearest value up and down , and then check if one of them is  your desired `ID` .

Comment: I would point out the fact that the `lead` and `lag` functions was introduced in 2012 version, since the OP didn't specify the version in his question. Also, Your query uses `lead` twice, when it should use `lead` and `lag`.

Comment: What does it matter if it uses `lead` twice? One is with `desc` and one with `asc` ordering.. I'll add a note about the version :)

Comment: I've added a link in the top and a little explanation @shahroz

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @id int = 4

select sn.*
from table sn
    inner join 
    (
    select top 2 sn_prev.*
    from table sn_prev
    where id <= @id
    order by id desc
    ) sp on sp.id= sn.id

union 

select sn.*
from table sn
    inner join 
    (
    select top 1 sn_prev.*
    from table sn_prev
    where id > @id
    order by id
    ) sp on sp.id = sn.id
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use MIN() and MAX() function in sql.