# How to find nearest entries before and after a value in Postresql

Tags: postgresql

Similar to this question: [How to find the first nearest value up and down in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38865947/how-to-find-the-first-nearest-value-up-and-down-in-sql)

I have a Postgres DB Table named `prices` structured as:

| id | column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | date_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.5 | 1.7 | 1.6 | 1234560000 |
| 2 | 0.9 | 1.1 | 1.0 | 1234570000 |
| 3 | 11.5 | 23.5 | 17.5 | 1234580000 |
| 4 | 8.3 | 12.3 | 10.3 | 1234600000 |

I'm trying to select either the row that matches exactly to an input date:

Example #1: input query for date_col = 1234580000 would return...

| id | column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | date_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.5 | 1.7 | 1.6 | 1234580000 |

or if that date does not exist, then retrieve the entries immediately before and after:

Example #2: input query for date_col = 1234590000 would return...

| id | column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | date_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 11.5 | 23.5 | 17.5 | 1234580000 |
| 4 | 8.3 | 12.3 | 10.3 | 1234600000 |

I attempted to mess around with the code from the similar question, but I am a bit stuck and have resorted to trying to get the original query date -> check if the DB returned anything in Python, then I create a broad range for the DB to return, send the second query, and then iterate over the returned result in Python. If the result still doesn't exist then I make the range larger... which I know is the wrong way, but my brain is too smooth for this haha

Current code that works when the entry does exist, but does not work  when the entry does not exist:

```
SELECT *
FROM prices, (SELECT id, next_val, last_val
             FROM (SELECT t.*,
                          LEAD(t.id, 1) OVER (ORDER BY t.date_col) as next_val,
                          LAG(t.id, 1) OVER (ORDER BY t.date_col)  as last_val
                   FROM prices AS t) AS s
             WHERE 1234580000 IN (s.date_col, s.next_val, s.last_val)) AS x
WHERE prices.id = x.id OR prices.id = x.next_val OR prices.id = x.last_val
```

based on the accepted answer this worked like a charm:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM prices WHERE prices.date_col <= 1234580000 ORDER BY prices.date_col DESC LIMIT 1) AS a UNION (SELECT * FROM prices WHERE prices.date_col >= 1234580000 ORDER BY prices.date_col ASC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Your first example output doesn't make any sense.  Typo?

Comment: tried to clarify the example a bit, hopefully, that helps

Comment: The issue is you say you are looking for row with `date_col = 1234580000`, but you are showing values(other then `date_col`) for row with `date_col = 1234560000`. So either you want `date_col = 1234560000` or you need  `3  11.5  23.5  17.5`.

Comment: My fault, I was hoping to return the whole row based on `date_col  = 1234580000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the simplest solution would be a `UNION`:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM prices
  WHERE date_col <= 1234580000
  ORDER BY date_col DESC
  LIMIT 1
UNION
  SELECT *
  FROM prices
  WHERE date_col >= 1234580000
  ORDER BY date_col ASC
  LIMIT 1
```